# Converting shapefile to ASC or LAZ format

Tags: shapefile, ascii, laz

Eire/Ireland data is available to buy, and I have a sample file.  It seems to be a zip of some files with SHP, PRJ, SHX and DBF extension.

I am trying to convert this data to LAZ format.  I can open the file in QGIS, via the browser, but I do not know how to translate/export the data.

I could use either LAZ data or ASC DTM data; Although I need classified LAZ's, I can convert DTM ASC data using RapidLasso lastools to assign ground (2) to the data and force-classify it, and then DemZip.exe to convert format.

I have successfully opened the file in QGIS, and I get a rectangle of block colour.  OSI provided a Height.csv file, which I have added as a layer, from a delimited file.  The Height file has X,Y,Z and AccurLevel fields, and I have mapped to X,Y and Z accordingly. The rectangle changes colour, and becomes zoomable.

How do I output this to LAS format?

Comment: Your “ESRI Project” is a shapefile.

Comment: Shapefile is not file geodatabase. If you provide details of what you have attempted, you are more likely to get a response on what needs to change.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Thanks for the explanation.  I was assuming it was a project because of the PRJ file.  Do you know if it is possible to convert this set of files to raster format, like ASC or DTM format?

Comment: @Vince With respect, closing this question seems restrictive and unhelpful.  I seek only guidance on how to convert a shapefile into raster format.  It occurs to me that other people might be in the same boat as me, and may value an answer to this question.  I have added what I have tried so far.  Once I get the data in a raster format, I should be good to go, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Your download is a shapefile (shapefile are constituted of several file but are just one dataset), this format store vector data and if you get just a rectangle it's likely a polygon dataset (could be the extend of the data your are after),you could try to zoom in to see if it is in fact point. You could also try to open the attribute table and see what information you get. After doing that update your question with what you find (picture could be helpfull) and it will likely be reopened.

Comment: LAS/LAZ isn't a raster format, it's a pointcloud format, which is more vector than raster. Passing a shapefile through raster to generate LAS will destroy the benefit of LiDAR collection. GIS SE is problem-solving site; we're not equipped to handle requests for "guidance and links" since these are *discussion-oriented* and *opinion-based*.

Comment: I rarely use QGIS but I suspect it’s possible. However, if your shapefile has only one rectangular polygon then it won’t make a useful DTM.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have a sample 'tile' from OSI, so the rectangle would explain that.  The opened shape file has a Scale and EPSG:2157 setting showing in QGIS, so I think it is sane.  The supplied zip contains a Height.csv file, four fields, X,Y,Z,AccurLevel.  I can they add a the Height.csv as a layer, connecting X,Y and Z appropriately, and my rectangle changes colour and becomes a grid that I can zoom in/out.  I think I now have a 3D space mapped to co-ords that could be output to LAS, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with that additional information. I am not a potential answerer of your question but that may help one to be attracted to it.

Comment: @PolyGeo Updated accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Dont know much about LAZ format but these link all suggest solution to convert to LAS/LAZ : https://pointly.ai/how-to-convert-your-point-cloud-data-into-las-laz/ ; https://opentopography.org/blog/las-conversion-tools-lastools-and-lasutility ; https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_someone_suggest_any_software_or_tool_to_convert_point_cloud_data_into_las_format2 ; https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/25nJVwe_4kk

Comment: Would the lastools "txt2las" function work using the 'Height file'?

Comment: @J.R Thanks for the links - they are close but I don't think they are exactly what I need.  I have an ESRI Shape and a height grid, and I need to convert this to LAS.  I am using QGIS because it will allow me to import the shape and blend the heights in, but then I do not know how to get it to drop out the data as LAS.

Comment: @cm1 Thanks for this, I have not used txt2las, but have used other RapidLasso tools.  This tool probably would not work because the height csv is just heights, and does not have any coordinate or projection data, which is in the shape file.  I knit the shape and the heights in QGIS, but then I am clueless.

Comment: What feature type do you 'knit' the the shape and the heights in QGIS to... a point shapefile?

Comment: @cm1 Sorry if not clear;  I assume the shape file is the 2D coordinate set and EPSG etc, and the Height file is a grid that maps onto it.  QGIS seems to allow me to bring the two together, but then I need to output to LAS.  Apologies, bit out of my own area of expertise so I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shapefile is not a point feature you could convert it to one with a few QGIS vector processing steps like 'Densify by...count/interval' then use SAGA tool 'Convert polygon/line vertices to points'.

Once you have a point feature you could add X, Y columns to the Attribute Table and use the Field Calculator to populate those fields with the Geometry values ($x & $y).

You could then assign your shapefile the height values using the 'Sample raster values' or 'Drape' tools in QGIS (you can find them in the Processing Toolbox, use the search feature there if needed). Name the column with prefix 'Z'.

[image: QGIS processing]

Save/export the new point feature as a .csv file. You may have to clean it up a bit to resemble the following format (note no header):

```
1,410449.469900,1303305.284000,0.199106916785240
2,466992.533900,1297022.722000,0.191032126545906
```

Then use RapidLasso tool ['txt2las'](http://lastools.org/download/txt2las_README.txt) to finally convert it to LAS.

```
 C:\LAStools\bin>txt2las64 -i D:\pt.txt -o D:\pt_lidar.las -parse pxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the shape file into another format (like CSV) using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html), then you can use [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html) to create a raster.

Comment: I have an ESRI shape file (X and Y) and a CSV of height values (Z) that corresponds.  The aim is to make either a LAS file, or an ASC file that I can use RapidLasso tools to convert to LAS.  Is that possible?  Thanks for the response.